# ReactJS how to update array state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on a tag feature in React and I am not sure how to update the tags.

***In TagsInput.js***

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CancelIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Cancel";

import "../../css/TagsInput.css";

function TagsInput(props) {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState(props.tags);
  const removeTags = (indexToRemove) => {
    setTags([...tags.filter((_, index) => index !== indexToRemove)]);
  };

  const addTags = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value !== "") {
      setTags([...tags, event.target.value]);
      props.selectedTags([...tags, event.target.value]);
      event.target.value = "";
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="tags-input">
      <ul id="tags">
        {tags.map((tag, index) => (
          <li key={index} className="tag">
            <span className="tag-title">{tag}</span>
            <CancelIcon className="tag-close-icon" onClick={() => removeTags(index)} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <input
        type="text"
        onKeyUp={(event) => (event.key === " " ? addTags(event) : null)}
        placeholder="Press space to add tags"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default TagsInput;
```

***In Post.js***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Post extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tag: ["test tag"],
    };
  }

  render() {
    const selectedTags = (tags) => {
      console.log(tags);
      this.setState({ tag: tags });
      console.log(this.state.tag);
    };

    const { subject, tag, question } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="post">
        <div className="post__container">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="post__textInput">
              <TagsInput
                selectedTags={selectedTags}
                tags={[]}
              />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The `console.log(tags)` just outputs an array of all the tags in the container, something like this:
`["1 ", "2 ", "3 ", "4 "]`. The `console.log(this.state.tag)` after the `this.setState` also outputs and array, but always one behind the `console.log(tags)`. i.e., when `console.log(tags)` outputs `["1"]`, `console.log(this.state.tag)` outputs `[""]`. when `console.log(tags)` outputs `["1", "2"]`, `console.log(this.state.tag)` outputs `["1"]`. Also, when I remove the tags, the state doesn't update. How can I fix this?

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous,  https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value

Answer (score 0):

In synthetic events, setState update the state asynchronously.After you setState, the console's value is always the value before the update

```
this.setState({ tag: tags }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.tag)
})
```